# Can you identify this Sega Genesis (Mega Drive) game from 1991 or before?

Tags: game-identification, sega-genesis

This is a screenshot from a Polish magazine (Top Secret #5 from 1991. Page #2). It is a Sega Genesis (Mega Drive) game. The game is surely in color, just the screenshot is black&white. The game cannot be newer than 1991.

Can you identify this game?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The game is Hokuto no Ken - Shin Seikimatsu Kyūseishu Densetsu. It's also known as Last Battle outside of Japan.

[image]